# Devise not performing an action after customizing redirects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, devise

After customizing the devise redirects to call and i want to perform an action like the i have a controller called stories controller and a before filter that says

`befroe_filter :authenticate_user!` it redirects me to the sign in page but does not send me back to the previous request after signing in. My code is as follows

```
  def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
      user_profile_path(current_user)
  end
```

How can i do it to redirect me to the previous action after signing in like the new action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change it to this:

```
def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
  stored_location_for(resource) || user_profile_path(current_user)
end
```